# How to get Youtube video by category in android?

Tags: android, youtube, categories, android-youtube-api, movies

I am trying to get [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/) video by category in android App like Movies and trailer but didn't find any help.

Can any one please help me for same.

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start is [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/articles/view_youtube_jsonc_responses).
You'll be able to build the url you want and use standard/3rd party lib to build the http request(I preffer OkHttp).